# Time Picker +,- Buttons issue in Android 4.0

Tags: android

In my app i have an activity in which i am using time picker,and in the time picker i am hiding '+','-' buttons for minutes part in order to restrict the user to change the minutes. It is working fine in android 3.x and it's below versions.But in android 4.0 it is not hiding the '+','-' Buttons of minutes, and the worst thing is if i am clicking on the '-' button of minutes it is changing hours. Any solutions for this??

Here is my Code snippet and Ref Images:

`timePicker.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
 try {
            ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) timePicker.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)
                    .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) timePicker.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(2)
                    .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }`

 [image: In Anadroid 3.X and it's Below Versions]   [image: In Android 4.0]